# Scaffold padding causes a lot of recompositions

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

1st code: a lot of recompositions on scroll

2nd code: these recompositions get skipped

I need to keep the structure of the first code (the one below is oversimplified version), and get the skipped recompositions of the second code. I guess I have to move the padding value some other way into the other composable, but I can't figure it out.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
) {
    val homeUiState by viewModel.homeUiState.collectAsState()
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            HarmonyTopAppBar(
                title = "Title",
                canNavigateBack = false,
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        HomeBody(
            homeUiState = homeUiState,
            innerPadding = innerPadding
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeBody(homeUiState: HomeUiState, innerPadding: PaddingValues) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
    ) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(homeUiState.habitList) { habit ->
                Text(
                    text = habit.name,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
) {
    val homeUiState by viewModel.homeUiState.collectAsState()
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            HarmonyTopAppBar(
                title = "Title",
                canNavigateBack = false,
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            LazyColumn {
                items(homeUiState.habitList) { habit ->
                    Text(
                        text = habit.name,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```